# R - function to get a list of database columns

Tags: r, function, statistics, summary, categorical-data

I have a database with multiple variables, both numerical and categorical. I would like to have summary descriptive statistics with R studio only for categorical variables (frequency, percentage) and i was thinking about a subset of the database isolated with a column list created with a function and then passing it to sapply -> prop.table. 
Unfortunately I'm stucked and i can only detect through the columns if they're categorical or not.

Thanks in advance, 
Angelo

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to iterate through your factor columns.

For example:

```
d <- data.frame( A=numeric(), B=logical(), C=character() )
for(col in which(sapply(d, is.factor)))
    print(col, names(d)[col], summary(d[,col]))  # print whatever statistics you want
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much. 

I did something like this

`descriptive <- function(dataset) {
  
  fattore<- lapply(dataset,class)
  
  for (j in seq(dataset)) {
    
    if (!fattore[j]=="factor")  {
      
      print(mean(dataset[,j], na.rm=T))
      
    }   else {
      
      print(table(dataset[j]))
    }
    
  }
  
}` 
but i haven't managed to get column titles...

Comment: See my updated answer. To get column names, use `names(df)`. You can then index it in order to access particular column names, e.g. `names(df)[1]`.